# PHP Query using WHERE, AND & OR Statement Issue

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I'm having problems understanding why my OR statement doesn't produce the results I want.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
orderheader.ordernumber As Order_Number
, ccilog.orderid AS Order_ID
, orderheader.billingcontactfirstname AS Customer_Name
, orderheader.billingcontactlastname AS Customer_Surname
, orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress AS Customer_Email
, orderheader.webbrandcode AS Brand_Code
, orderitems.productname AS Product_Name
, orderitems.qty AS Item_Qty
, orderheader.datecreated AS Order_Date 
FROM orderheader 
LEFT JOIN ccilog ON orderheader.id=ccilog.orderid
LEFT JOIN orderitems ON ccilog.orderid=orderitems.orderid 
WHERE orderitems.status = '0' 
AND orderheader.status != '1'
AND orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand1' || orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand2' 
AND orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress != 'email1@email.co.uk'
AND orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress != 'email2@email.co.uk'
"))
```

If I remove the line:

```
AND orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand1' || orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand2'
```

My results display ok and my rules work displaying Brand1, 2 and 3. When I add the above line in, I expect to see the same results but without brand 3. Brand 3 doesn't show which is great, but it seems that now it lists all of brand 2 and not just the rows where the previous order status statements are true.

I can't understand why my results are not just returning the 11 results I expect (It's returns 425) almost most of Brand 2's results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parentheses around the OR clause...it should read:

```
(orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand1' || orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand2')
```

When you don't put parens, then the constraints get associated using operator precedence, which may not be what you intend!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
orderheader.ordernumber As Order_Number
, ccilog.orderid AS Order_ID
, orderheader.billingcontactfirstname AS Customer_Name
, orderheader.billingcontactlastname AS Customer_Surname
, orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress AS Customer_Email
, orderheader.webbrandcode AS Brand_Code
, orderitems.productname AS Product_Name
, orderitems.qty AS Item_Qty
, orderheader.datecreated AS Order_Date 
FROM orderheader 
LEFT JOIN ccilog ON orderheader.id=ccilog.orderid
LEFT JOIN orderitems ON ccilog.orderid=orderitems.orderid 
WHERE orderitems.status = '0' 
AND orderheader.status != '1'
AND (orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand1' || orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand2')
AND orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress != 'email1@email.co.uk'
AND orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress != 'email2@email.co.uk'
"))
```

See:

> You can also combine AND and OR (use parenthesis to form complex
>   expressions).

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE
LastName='Svendson'
AND (FirstName='Tove' OR FirstName='Ola')
```

-> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
....AND orderheader.status != '1'
AND ( orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand1' || orderitems.webbrandcode = 'brand2' )
AND orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress != 'email1@email.co.uk'...
```